# Maven dependency list for stardog examples

Tags: stardog

Could someone please post the maven dependencies needed to run the stardog 2.1.3 client examples? These critical ones keep coming up undefined

```
import com.complexible.common.openrdf.OpenRdfIO; 
import com.complexible.common.protocols.server.Server; 
import com.complexible.stardog.Stardog;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Server` and `Stardog` are in the `${STARDOG}\server` directory of the distribution; these are not installed by the maven install script because they're server dependencies and normally not needed in a client application.  The complete end-to-end examples, because they include both client & server code, require both sets of dependencies.

The `OpenRdfIO` class no longer exists, you are using out of data code.  If you use the version of the example in the distribution, it will have the correct class name.